# What's the easiest way to get an equivalent to GNU grep that supports negative lookbehinds?

Tags: regex, perl, grep, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to grep through a bunch of files in nested subdirectories to look for regular expression matches; my regex requires negative lookbehind.

Perl has negative lookbehind, but as far as I can tell [GNU grep doesn't support negative lookbehinds](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html).

What's the easiest way to get an equivalent to GNU grep that supports negative lookbehinds?

(I guess I could write my own mini-grep in Perl, but that doesn't seem like it should be necessary.  My copy of the Perl Cookbook includes source for tcgrep; is that what I should use?  If so, where's the latest version?  Don't tell me I have to type this entire program!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com)! Ack is written in Perl so it uses Perl's regex engine (by default).

The negative look-behind is `ack "(?<!bad)boy"` (per willert's comment)

Comment: I thought someone might suggest this, but I don't think ack uses negative lookbehind.  For example, I created a temp file in a temp directory containing two lines: "goodboy" and "badboy" and then used the sample from Perl in a Nutshell: `ack "(?<!=bad)boy"` ... it returned both lines.  If the regex were being followed, only the "goodboy" line should return. (I'll reverse my downvote if you turn out to be right after all.)

Comment: The negative look-behind is <code>ack "(?<!bad)boy"</code>, get away with the <code>=</code>

Comment: WTF? "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited."  @too much php, make an edit and I'll fix it, sorry. :-(

Comment: `!` in `ack "(?<!bad)boy"` will be intercepted by bash (`bash: !bad: event not found`), use single quotes `ack '(?<!bad)boy'`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a comment from other [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/87203/5014). I've found that negative lookbehind is experimentally supported in `grep` with the `-P/--perl-regexp` option, so you may still not need to use a different tool if you prefer to keep using `grep`.

By the way, my preferred alternative to `grep` is [`grin`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin) (which is written in python).