# osx grep using negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, macos

in osx (mac) command line i try to use grep command :

```
grep '(?<!class) cselectnone' -s *
```

it should match **'def cselectnone()'** but NOT **'class cselectnode()'**.
But in fact i can't match 'def cselectnone()'.

I try this code using http://regexr.com/v1/ and https://regex101.com/
And i got the correct result. But the result in osx command line was not correct . Why is  it?

Comment: Have you tried `grep -P ...`?

Comment: And assuming `grep -P` isn't an option, just `grep 'cselectnone' | grep -v 'class'`?

Comment: @AntonSavin -P didn't work.

Comment: @Mr.Llama : yes i can use that grep -v. I'm just curious with that code. it should fine ( tested on regex101) , i need the reason why it breaks?

Comment: @andio - Simply put, the default GNU grep [doesn't support negative lookbehinds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490018/477563).  If your version of grep supports the `-P` option for PCRE, that should work.  If not, you may need to consider tackling this differently.

Comment: @Mr.Llama : i see ... i thought GNU grep has full compatibility.  Thanks.